# Approximate bounding box for chemfig figure

Tags: chemfig, bounding-box

If I wanted LaTeX to automatically make an approximate bounding box for, say, the following figure, could I use some built-in feature of the chemfig package? Or would I need to code this up in plain TeX or could I do it using the pgf package?

[image]

It's easy enough to do this manually with the following code:

```
$\chemfig{[,0.65]@{1}CH_3@{2}CH_2@{3}CH_2@{4}CH@{9}CH_2@{10}CH_2@{11}C@{12}H_3(-[:90,,7]@{5}CH_2@{6}CH_2@{7}C@{8}H_3)}$
\chemmove{
    \path[-,draw] ([xshift=-4pt]1.north) -- (2.north) -- (3.north) -- ([xshift=-4pt]4.north) --
    ([xshift=-4pt]5.north) -- (6.north) -- (7.north) -- ([xshift=7pt]8.north)
    -- ([xshift=7pt]8.south) -- (7.south) -- (6.south) -- (9.north) -- (10.north)
    -- (11.north) -- ([xshift=8pt]12.north) -- ([xshift=8pt]12.south) -- 
    (11.south) -- (10.south) -- (9.south) -- (4.south)-- (3.south) -- (2.south) -- 
    ([xshift=-4pt]1.south) -- cycle;
}
```

which gives

[image]

But I was wondering if there's a way to hook into chemfig's internals and have TeX or pgf work out the bounding box automatically and, perhaps, "return" it as a list.

Thanks!

EDIT: I know how I could do something like this in theory. I could write a macro to iterate through the chemfig argument, i.e., [,0.65]CH_3CH_2CH_2CHCH_2CH_2CH_3(-[:90,,7]CH_2CH_2CH_3), place an @ sign before each atom, store the location of each corner of each node (north, south, east, west, etc) in a variable, and then apply a simple (in theory) algorithm to find the polygonal boundary of the structure with these nodes acting as points in the 2-d plane, but I'm hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Did you already try `\setchemfig{debug=true}`?  Combined with your molecule, you get the following output https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmljh.png which admittedly is not identical to the one in your question but depending on the intended use case probably good enough.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for the reply. I'm not looking for a visual output so much as I am an actual bounding box that I can run some computations on. Is there anyway to get chemfig to store this bounding box in a variable?